# executing a program in shell script linux

Tags: android, linux, shell

I have a program which im trying to execute through shell script

This is the command to execute the program
`/data/local/tmp/dbus/dbus-run-session --dbus-daemon=/data/local/tmp/dbus/dbus-daemon --config-file=/data/local/tmp/dbus/session.conf sh`

if i run the program directly without shell script this works fine

But when i put this same command in a shell script and run the shell script i get the following error

**Permission deniediled to exec 'sh**

if i remove the **sh** from the end of the command i get the error that a **non-option argument is required**.

its not a chmod +x  issue since the script is running and i have done the chmod already

**PS. I'm running this shell script on the android terminal**

does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the whole shell script.

Comment: /data/local/tmp/dbus/dbus-run-session --dbus-daemon=/data/local/tmp/dbus/dbus-daemon --config-file=/data/local/tmp/dbus/session.conf sh


this is the only command i have in the shell script

Comment: basically the command /data/local/tmp/dbus/dbus-run-session --dbus-daemon=/data/local/tmp/dbus/dbus-daemon --config-file=/data/local/tmp/dbus/session.conf sh needs a sh at the end to execute otherwise it complains that a non-option argument is required.
If i remove the sh and run the script as sh <script_name> it complains because of the missing sh at the end

Comment: Depends on a bunch of details we don't have. For all we know, you're on a system with SELinux in enforcing mode and dbus isn't *allowed* to run `/bin/sh` except via terminal invocation.

Comment: ...which is to say, this quite likely **isn't** a question about shell scripting and is instead a configuration issue.

Comment: I agree. I just tried this on my Debian 9 machine and it runs just fine. Perhaps elaborate on your system configuration.

Comment: im running it on the terminal in android

Comment: and if i run the shell command as a super user i get the following error 
**No such file or directoryexec 'sh**

Answer (score -2):

You likely need to use `chmod +x <yourscript.sh>` This should give the script permission to run!

Comment: i have done the chmod +x already
The script does run, but is complaining about the sh command at the end